# Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerparserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: ajax, scriptmanager

Hi I am getting below Error
"Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerparserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed"

When I click button on my User Control. User control does not have any Update Panel but the page in which user control will be loaded has an update panel.

I don't see this issue on my local machine, I get this only when I DEPLOY to server..

How can I fix this and also how Can I Test this as it does not show error in local machine ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution. Nothing given in online blogs matched to my issues, problem was from database side.

Tahnks..!!